# Multidimensional Array: How to get all values of a specific key?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an multidimensional array which includes IDs and URLs. I would like to output the URLs only.

```
$abstract_details = array(
                        array(
                            'id' => 68769782222,
                            'url' => 'http://yourclick.ch'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'id' => 111,
                            'url' => 'http://google.com'
                        )
                    );

foreach ($abstract_details as $abstract_detail) {
    foreach ($abstract_detail as $get_abstract_detail) {
        $result .= $get_abstract_detail . '<br>';
    }
}
```

When I run my code I get both information. How is it possible to take control of what I want to show?

Comment: To get the url: `foreach ($abstract_details as $abstract_detail) { echo $abstract_detail['url'] . '<br>';}`. Run it: [https://eval.in/605347](https://eval.in/605347)

Comment: Please read this : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing

Comment: @FirstOne I don't even know why I thought that it needs to be complicated but that just works fine. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need nested loop here, if you want to print only the url. Try this:

```
foreach ($abstract_details as $abstract_detail) {
   $result .= $abstract_detail['url'] . '<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
http://yourclick.ch
http://google.com
```

Answer (score 17):

Use [**`array_column`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) that will prevent you from foreach loop

```
$url = array_column($abstract_details, 'url');

echo implode('<br/>', $url);
```

Comment: You could simply implode the array. I really appreciate the use of array_column. Using foreach would ruin the former. :)

Comment: This is a nice function. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($abstract_details as $abstract_detail) {
       $result .= $abstract_detail['url']
    }
```